# Android: Draw gif on canvas only once

Tags: android, canvas, gif

So I know how to draw a looping gif on a `Canvas` using this code:

```
long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
if(gifStart == 0)
    gifStart = now;
if(gif != null) {
    int dur = gif.duration();
    int relTime = (int)((now-gifStart)%dur);
    gif.setTime(relTime);

    gif.draw(canvas, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

but how can I adapt this so that way once the gif is done (looped only once) it stops looping and just draws the last frame in the gif (don't have it restart the gif)?

Comment: `setTime(dur)` (or `dur - 1` - you have to check both )

Comment: @pskink but how would I check if the gif (`Movie`) is done playing?

Comment: you have `gifStart`, use it

Comment: @pskink well I have used `if(now - gifStart > dur) {}` which has worked before but doesn't seem to be working for this.

Comment: yes, its good check

Comment: @pskink turns out the if statement was working the emulator was just so laggy I didn't realize it was working lol